# Pandas.dataframe.read_table() ignores my row labels

Tags: pandas

So I am an R programmer and I was told "hey, this pandas python module makes the switch to python easy."

Ok, so I wrote the following code to try it out.

```
geneExpress = pandas.read_table("./exon_train.txt")
print(geneExpress.columns)
print(geneExpress.index)
```

To my horror, my row labels have been replaced with integers.
Please forgive my noobness.
Is **df.index** the equivalent command to R's **rownames(df)**? 
Are my labels lost or just hidden somewhere?

I also searched extensively and I am starting to feel like no one has asked my question before... making me a bit bashful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having read the data you can set the index to any column. If, for example, your row labels are in a column called "rowlabel" you'd do:

```
geneExpress.set_index('rowlabel', inplace=True)
```

For next time you can specify that a particular column be used as row labels using the `index_col` keyword argument, e.g. to use the values in the first column as the index:

```
geneExpress = pandas.read_table("./exon_train.txt", index_col=0)
```